# Side bar menu in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

How can I add side bar menu(when I right click on file) only for files or only for folders? For example if I add this code to `"Side Bar.sublime-menu"`:

```
{ "caption": "New command", "command": "my_command", "args": {"files": []} }
```

I will get new option for all files and folders in sidebar.

How I can add this option only for files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MyCommandCommand` class, add an `is_enabled()` method. From the [ST2 API docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html):

> Returns true if the command is able to be run at this time. The default implementation simply always returns True.

Something like

```py
def is_enabled(self, paths=[]):
    self.has_files = False
    for path in paths:
        if os.path.isdir(path) == False:
            self.has_files = True
        if self.has_files:
            break
    return self.has_files
```

should work. (warning: not well-tested!)

There is another option, and that is to either rely on an existing install of [`SideBarEnhancements`](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements), or to borrow `sidebar/SideBarSelection.py` and include it in your source. This way, you can just call either

```py
from SideBarEnhancements.sidebar.SideBarSelection import SideBarSelection
# if depending on an existing install
```

or

```py
from .SideBarSelection import SideBarSelection
# if using the file in your own code - probably the best way to go
```

at the top of your `.py` file. Then, in your `MyCommandCommand` class, use the following:

```py
def is_enabled(self, paths = []):
    return SideBarSelection(paths).hasFiles()
```

and you'll be all set.

I highly recommend reading through the source of `SideBarEnhancements`, there may be other features there that you can use as well.

Finally, please be aware that `SideBarEnhancements` is no longer being supported for Sublime Text 2. Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684911/side-bar-menu-in-sublime-text/22699846#22699846) explaining why and how to work around it if you still need to run it in ST2. There's also a link to download an ST2-compatible zip file of the source, if needed. More and more plugins are migrating to ST3-only versions, as there are significant enhancements in the API that make maintaining identical features in both versions a real pain sometimes. If the plugin you are writing is for public use, please make sure it is compatible with both ST2 and ST3 before releasing it.

Good luck!